# [ask]Join two table

Tags: php, mysql

first query

```
SELECT material_name,material_type,original,vr,repro,scrap FROM stock_opname
```

have 88 result

second query

```
  SELECT t.material_name,t.material_type, 
         (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM temp_data_transaction where material_name=t.material_name and destination = 'WAREHOUSE_RESIN' and kind_of_transaction = 'ORIGINAL') as 'total_original',
         (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM temp_data_transaction where material_name=t.material_name and destination = 'WAREHOUSE_RESIN' and kind_of_transaction = 'VR') as 'total_vr', 
         (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM temp_data_transaction where material_name=t.material_name and destination = 'WAREHOUSE_RESIN' and kind_of_transaction = 'SCRAP') as 'total_scrap', 
         (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM temp_data_transaction where material_name=t.material_name and destination = 'WAREHOUSE_RESIN' and kind_of_transaction = 'REPRO') as 'total_repro',
         (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM temp_data_transaction where material_name=t.material_name and source = 'WAREHOUSE_RESIN' and kind_of_transaction = 'ORIGINAL') as 'total_original_out',
         (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM temp_data_transaction where material_name=t.material_name and source = 'WAREHOUSE_RESIN' and kind_of_transaction = 'VR') as 'total_vr_out', 
         (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM temp_data_transaction where material_name=t.material_name and source = 'WAREHOUSE_RESIN' and kind_of_transaction = 'REPRO') as 'total_repro_out',
         (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM temp_data_transaction where material_name=t.material_name and source = 'WAREHOUSE_RESIN' and kind_of_transaction = 'SCRAP') as 'total_scrap_out'
         FROM temp_data_transaction t GROUP BY material_name
```

have 6 result

question
how to join query two inside query one ?

thanks

Comment: I think a better question is how to streamline all those sums, up.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix , ok how to streamline and join query two inside query one ?

Comment: Why do you need it all one query, there is nothing wrong with using multiple queries.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix  if two query run one by one , no problem , but if query two inside to one..not have idea..